# how to find an id if not passed in view?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get subject id from subject table so that I can save the relevant keywords to the that subject in which they keywords are added. I have added this in a different way by assigning my `<select>` tag the value of subject id but that is not a good practice as now I cant be able to add subject to the relevant id. I need to get an id of the subject so I can add the subject to the relevant user and the keywords to the relevant subject. Any help ?

This is my VIEW

```
        @section('content1')
        <p>Mentor Subject:
        @foreach($subjects as $s)
        <li> {{ $s['subject_name'] }} <a href="">Edit</a><a href="">Delete</a> 
        </li>
        @endforeach
        </p>

        <p> Specified Keywords: 
        @foreach($subjectKeywords as $sk)
            <li> {{ $sk ['keyword_title1'] }} </li>
            <li> {{ $sk ['keyword_title2'] }} </li>
            <li> {{ $sk ['keyword_title3'] }} </li>
            <li> {{ $sk ['keyword_title4'] }} </li>
            <li> {{ $sk ['keyword_title5x'] }} </li>
        @endforeach
        </p>

        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" role="form"  action="/add-new-subject" >

        {{ csrf_field() }}


        <div class="form-group" data-rule="required">
            <label>Subject Titles</label> <br/>

           <select id="ddselect" name='subject_name' class="signup" required >
                <option value=""> Select Subject to Monitor </option>
                @foreach($subjectDetails as $s)
                    <option id={{ $s['id'] }} name={{ $s['id'] }} value={{ 
                     $s['id'] }}>{{ $s['subject_name'] }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

            <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="k1" class="signup-control form" id="k1" placeholder="Keyword 1"/>
            <div class="validation"></div>

            <input type="text" name="k2" class="signup-control form" id="k2" placeholder="Keyword 2"/>
            <div class="validation"></div>

            <input type="text" name="k3" class="signup-control form" id="k3" placeholder="Keyword 3"/>
            <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="k4" class="signup-control form" id="k4" placeholder="Keyword 4"/>
            <div class="validation"></div>

            <input type="text" name="k5" class="signup-control form" id="k5" placeholder="Keyword 5"/>
            <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <br/>

        <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!-- Button -->
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="form contact-form-button light-form-button oswald light">Select Subject</button>
        </div>
        </form>

        @endsection        
        @endsection
```

This is my CONTROLLER

```
        public function showSubject() {

        if(Auth::user()->id) {
            $subjects = Subject::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

            $subjectDetails = Subject::all();
            $subjectKeywords = SubjectKeyword::all();

            return view('mentor\showSubject', compact('subjects', 'subjectDetails', 'subjectKeywords'));

        }else {
            Session::flash("message", "Please sign in to access this page");
            return redirect('/signup');
        }
        // echo Auth::user()->id;
        // die();
        return view('mentor\showSubject');
         }

        public function addNewSubject() {

        if(Auth::user()->id) {
            $s1 = Input::get('subject_name');

            $subjects = new Subject();
            $subjects->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $subjects->subject_name = $s1;

            // echo $s1;

            $k1 = Input::get('k1');
            $k2 = Input::get('k2');
            $k3 = Input::get('k3');
            $k4 = Input::get('k4');
            $k5 = Input::get('k5');

            $sk = new SubjectKeyword();
            $sk->subject_id = $s1;
            $sk->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $sk->keyword_title1 = $k1;
            $sk->keyword_title2 = $k2;
            $sk->keyword_title3 = $k3;
            $sk->keyword_title4 = $k4;
            $sk->keyword_title5 = $k5;

            $sk->save();

            Session::flash("message", "Your keywords are saved");
            return redirect('/subjects');


        }else {
            Session::flash("message", "Please sign in to access this page");
            return redirect('/signup');
        }
    }
```

This is my ROUTE

```
        Route::get('/subjects', 'MentorController@showSubject');
        Route::post('/add-new-subject', 'MentorController@addNewSubject');
```

I want to get an id of subjects so that I can add relevant keywords to the subjects. e.g. if user adds CS as a subject then i'll get its id and save all keywords to it.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Hello Asad,
  public function showSubject($id){
$subject = Subject::findOrFail($id);
}

I think this is what you are looking for but you need to have id in your route.. so  Route::get('/subjects/{id}', 'MentorController@showSubject');

Comment: hello kusy, thank you for your comment. I have tried doing that too but then it says `undefined object id` in the view. I even tried `action = ".../subjects[0]->id` which is working but returning the same id everytime I run the code. I also tried `action = "{{ route ('subjects', ['id' => $s->id }}" ` which didnt work. 

I think I am missing the simple id pass to get the id and failing to do that

Comment: `$subjects = new Subject();
            $subjects->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $subjects->subject_name = $s1;`
you have to save the `$subjects` as well here, so at the end `$subjects->save();` and then you can reffer to it I think

Comment: if you see, the value of subject's field is its primary key which is integer so cant subject_title as an integer in my table. This is actually the problem if I try to save the name then cant be able to save the id and vice versa. The above code is working but I need to save both subject_title and keywords to subjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          <select id="ddselect" name='subject_name' class="signup" required >

          <option value=""> Select Subject to Monitor </option>

           @foreach($subjectDetails as $s)
                <option value={{ $s['id'] }}>{{ $s['subject_name'] }}</option>
           @endforeach

        </select>
```

//in your controller you can get your id by subject_name

```
        $s1 = Input::get('subject_name');
    //after that get subject name based on that id 
        $sample=DB::table('tablename')->where('id',$s1)->first();
   //then you can store both id and name separately
        $subjects = new Subject();
        $subjects->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $subjects->subject_name = $sample->subjectname;
```